# Is there a clean T-SQL query I can use to verify an index has the right columns?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I am writing a DB upgrade script that will check to see if an index has the right two columns defined.  If it doesn't, or if it only has one of them, then I will DROP it (is there a way to ALTER an index?) and then recreate it with both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have a database immediately on-hand to test this, but you should be able to see if a column exists in an index by using the following IF EXISTS statement.

I'm not sure whether you can alter an index on the fly.

```
IF EXISTS
(
   SELECT MyIndex.Name AS IndexName, 
          Columns.name AS ColumnName 
   FROM sys.indexes MyIndex
   INNER JOIN sys.index_columns IndexColumns 
      ON  MyIndex.index_id = IndexColumns.index_id
      AND MyIndex.object_id = IndexColumns.object_id 
   INNER JOIN sys.columns Columns
      ON  Columns.column_id = IndexColumns.column_id 
      AND IndexColumns.object_id = Columns.object_id 
   WHERE Columns.name = 'ColumnName'
   AND MyIndex.Name='IX_MyIndexName'
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your help, Ed.  Here is the solution I wrote using yours as a start.  It has been verified.  Basically it has all of the correct joins.

```
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT i.Name AS IndexName, c.Name AS ColumnName
    FROM sys.indexes i
        JOIN sys.index_columns ic
            ON i.object_id = ic.object_id AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
        JOIN sys.columns c
            ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
    WHERE c.Name = 'MyColumnName' AND i.Name='MyIndexName'
)
```

Comment: I fixed my response to include that other join condition. I'm glad that I could be of assistance. You might consider marking your or my answer as correct.